# Laravel 5.4 Redirect after authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have the following in my RedirectifAuthenticated middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('dashboard');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

But when a user logs in, this is redirecting to /home which I renamed to /dashboard.

I have changed the routes, views etc from home to dashboard.

I have run a search throughout the whole projects and I cannot find a route to /home or a mention of home that is not the title or in unrelated filed such as the yarn.lock file.

I have found many articles on this issue but I do not have an Authenticate.php not do I have the old Auth middleware.

EDIT: Below are my Login Controller and routes:

LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
    public function authenticated(Request $request)
    {
        // Logic that determines where to send the user
        if($request->user()->hasRole('Stallhollder')){
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
        if($request->user()->hasRole('Manager')){
            return redirect('/dashboard2');
        }
    }
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
Route::resource('/bookings', 'BookingsController');
Route::get('/dashboard2', function () {
    return view('dashboard2');
});
```

Comment: Can you post your `LoginController`? And maybe `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware as well

Comment: @Luke.... Please Post Your `Routes Code` ... And `View` File

Comment: @ka_lin Sorry, got my wires crossed

Comment: @MatthewDaly: No probs :) happy coding

Comment: When You Call the dashboard..in url  `Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');` its go to `index` page and `index` page redirect to home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The default Laravel login controller](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php) sets the value of `$redirectTo` to '/home'. You need to update that to the new route as that defines where it gets redirected to after login.

Answer (score 0):

> **After `Run` The `php artisan make:auth` you have the following controllers.**

- LoginController
- RegisterController
- ResetPasswordController.php
- ForgotPasswordController.php

> Now, In Controller File Change The redirect to `dashboard`
>
> **Example:** `protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';`

### Example  ( LoginController )

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
  
   
use AuthenticatesUsers;


protected function authenticated(Request $request)
{
 
// Logic that determines where to send the user
    if($request->user()->hasRole('Stallhollder')){
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
    if($request->user()->hasRole('Manager')){
        return redirect('/dashboard2');
    }
   
  public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
  }

}
```

### Example  ( Routes )

```
<?php

Auth::routes();  // First Line Is `Auth::routes();`

Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');

Route::resource('/bookings', 'BookingsController');

Route::get('/dashboard2', function () {
    return view('dashboard2');
});

?>
```

### Example  ( RedirectifAuthenticated middleware )

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```